# Word2Vec word not found with Gensim but shows up on TensorFlow embedding projector?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I've recently started experimenting with pre-trained word embeddings to enhance the performance of my LSTM model on a NLP task. In this case, I looked into Google's Word2Vec. Based on online tutorials, I first downloaded Word2Vec with `wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz` and used python's `gensim` package to query the embeddings, using the following code.

```py
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("./data/word2vec/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin", binary=True)
    print(model["bosnia"])
```

However, after noticing that many common words weren't found in the model, I started to wonder if something was awry. I tried searching for `bosnia` in the embedding repo, as shown above, but it wasn't found. So, I went on the [TensorFlow embedding projector](https://projector.tensorflow.org/), loaded the Word2Vec model, and searched for `bosnia` - it was there.

So, my question is: why is this happening? Was the version of Word2Vec I downloaded not complete? Or is gensim unable to load all words into memory and therefore omitting some?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the length of the downloaded file(s), to ensure it's as expected (in case it was truncated or incompletely downloaded).

You should double-check that you're using the same file in both places, and also checking the exact same token (eg `'bosnia'` vs `'Bosnia'`) via both paths. (None of the 5 options in the https://projector.tensorflow.org/ drop-down correspond to the `GoogleNews` 300-d, 3-million-token dataset, and the `load` button doesn't appear to support word2vec `.bin` files, so I'm not sure how that could be used to cross-check what's in that file.)

(There aren't any known bugs in gensim's `load_word2vec_format()` that would explain it missing vectors that are actually present.)